# ajax result not populating element immediately

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
function getVenues(categoryId) {
                    var venues = "";
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetVenues", "Team")' + "?categoryId=" + categoryId, function (data) {
                       success: $.each(data, function (a, b) {
                            venues += "<option value='" + b.Value + "'>" + b.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                        $('#venuelist').html(venues);
                    });
                   var venueId= $('#venuelist').val();
                    getVenueNotes(categoryId, venueId);
                };
```

The problem is that the dropdownlist is not immediately being populated when  $('#venuelist').html(venues); is called. So without that, I can't get the valueId to pass to the next getVenueNotes() function.  However the dropdownlist is being populated when I just let it run.  When debugging and stepping through the deep jquery code, it gets populated after around 15 step through on this very long line of code that starts with:

```
}p&&o(s,c,p,l)},n.async?4===u.readyState?setTimeout(r):(a=++W.....
```

So I'm guessing there is something to do with readystate, but how do I pause the execution of my function until the data has been brought in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by attaching the done() method to .getJSON() like this:

```
 function getVenues(categoryId) {
                    var venues = "";
                    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetVenues", "Team")' + "?categoryId=" + categoryId, function(data) {
                        success: $.each(data, function(a, b) {
                            venues += "<option value='" + b.Value + "'>" + b.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                    }).done(function () {
                        $('#venuelist').html(venues);
                        var venueId = $('#venuelist').val();
                        getVenueNotes(categoryId, venueId);

                    });


                };
```